# Can a View on a PopupWindow display a PopupMenu?

Tags: android, popupwindow, popupmenu

In Android API11+ I'm displaying a button inside a PopupWindow. I'd like to show a PopupMenu when the button is clicked, without closing the PopupWindow. Is this possible at all?
I'm instantiating and initilizing the PopupMenu, but when I call popupMenu.show()
I'm getting this error (LogCat + partial call stack):

02-25 13:31:38.281: W/WindowManager(528): Attempted to add window with token that is a sub-window: android.os.BinderProxy@41316cc8.  Aborting.
02-25 13:31:51.257: D/AndroidRuntime(7643): Shutting down VM
02-25 13:31:51.257: W/dalvikvm(7643): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a711f8)
02-25 13:31:51.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7643): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 13:31:51.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7643): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@419c3458 is not valid; is your activity running?
[rest of stack]

Is this because the PopupMenu uses another PopupWindow which does not seem te be allowed from a PopupWindow? Same code runs OK when I hook it up to a button in the Activity content view.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

You can't anchor a PopupMenu from a PopupWindow view what you can do is define or anchor from a view inside roow view or top-level view here is an example:

main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IVoptionsMenuInvis"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="25"            
            android:paddingBottom="6dp"
            android:paddingTop="6dp">

</FrameLayout>
```

popupwindow.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/settingseditback"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IVoptionsMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:onClick="showSettingsPopup2"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp"
            android:paddingTop="6dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_actionbar_overflow_dark" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and finally your MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
.
.
.
    public void showSettingsPopup2(View v) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, findViewById(R.id.IVoptionsMenuInvis));
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, popup.getMenu());
        popup.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note "I'd like to show a PopupMenu when the button is clicked, without closing the PopupWindow". I tried your solution, but it causes the popup window to close.

Comment: No it's not, I'm using it in my own app, you can check my answer to my own question and check codes that i'm using [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24770364/3111479)