# Initiate PopupMenu inside from another PopupWindow

Tags: android

Hi guys I need to initiate PopupMenu from a button that is inside another popupWindow, the problem is that when i'm placing this button inside activity's root view it worked without any error but when I want to initiate it from another popupWindow it give's error. here is my code that i'm using:

this is my PopupWindow:

```
public void initiateSettingsPopupWindow() {

    LayoutInflater settingsInflate = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View settingsLayout = settingsInflate.inflate(R.layout.settings_popup,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls));

    PopupWindow swindo = new PopupWindow(settingsLayout, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
    swindo.showAtLocation(settingsLayout, Gravity.BOTTOM,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    swindo.setAnimationStyle(R.style.PopupWindowAnimation);
    LinearLayout settingsLinear = (LinearLayout) settingsLayout
            .findViewById(R.id.settingseditback);
    settingsLinear.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

and this is my PopupMenu code:

```
public void showSettingsPopup(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getBaseContext(), v);
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
}
```

and here is my xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/settingseditback"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:background="#ededed"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    .
    .
    .
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IVoptionsMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:onClick="showSettingsPopup"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp"
            android:paddingTop="6dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_actionbar_overflow_dark" >
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

What is the problem? and this question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067184/can-a-view-on-a-popupwindow-display-a-popupmenu) but no answer yet.
I tried every possible way that is given in internet,but no success yet.

Please give me a solution i'm really stuck in this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the solution by a little trick and i'm sharing it so if someone need it. My solution isn't so great but it works without any visual difference and problem, so maybe it help in some case.
I created one button in main xml file and in exact same place with the original button in PopupWindow, and in PopupMenu code I replaced v with reference for invisible button, here is my code:

```
public void showSettingsPopup2(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getBaseContext(), findViewById(R.id.IVoptionsMenuInvis));
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
}
```

Comment: thank you very much @Easyfast this works. but only when we are using view from layout file. (talking about second parameter) -> `PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getBaseContext(), findViewById(R.id.IVoptionsMenuInvis));`

but it doesn't work when we are using view from `PopupWindow`

Answer (score 0):

You can't anchor a PopupMenu to a view in a PopupWindow. You will need to anchor it to a View in a top-level window.

Comment: So what should i do? Can you please give me a solution or sample code?